# How to obtain the solution of this 2nd order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivation-of-formulae

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Pk3.jpg)

I am trying to derivate an equation and i got stuck right there because there is an x dot square and  i dont have any idea how to continue that. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It would help to know which equation you're trying to derive. Also, as @JoséCarlosSantos said, you really need to type this in mathjax.